# multiple iterations of a loop - population model

Tags: r

I have a 5 year age structured population model. I'm trying to repeat the model 100 times (to get variance). I'm struggling with the best way to do this probably because I'm not sure how to repeat the year 1 to year 5 outcomes 100 times. In other words, the simulation shouldn't do year 1 100 times then year 2 100 times because the population in year 1 carries over into year 2.

```
# INITIALIZE VARIABLES
sum_mat <- matrix(rep(0,3*3),nrow=3)  # Template for summer matrix
cc <- c(0.46,0.33,0.16,0.36,0.42)     # Observed calf:cow ratios

nyears <- 5 # 5 year population model

sims <- 100 # simulate the 5 year population model 100 times

#for (k in 1:sims){

# LOOP THROUGH YEARS
for (i in 1:nyears){

# CONDITION INPUT VARIABLES BY FIRST VS ALL OTHER YEARS
if (i == 1) {
onf  <- 0                 # Initial number of calves (hypothetical population)
ony  <- 250                   # Initial number of yearlings
ona2 <- 500                   # Initial number of cows

} else {
onf  <- 0                     # No calves in new pre-summer year 
ony  <- pops[1]               # Calves during post-summer are now yearlings
ona2 <- pops[2]+pops[3]       # Yearlings during post-summer now adults,added to existing summer adults
}

# SUMMER
pop0 <- c(onf,onf,onf,
        ony,ony,ony,
        ona2,ona2,ona2)       # Vector of age structure at the beginning of summer

  cc2=0

for (j in seq_along(cc)){   # Sample from observed calfcow ratios in order  of list   
  cc2[j]=cc[i]
  }

cowsurv=rnorm(n=1,mean=0.1,sd=.05)  # Randomly select mortality rate for females

sy_s  <- (1-(cowsurv))              # Yearlings summer survival
sa2_s <- (1-(cowsurv))              # Adult summer survival

# Leslie matrix for summer
sum_mat[1,] <- c(0,sy_s*cc2[j],sa2_s*cc2[j])  # Fecundity
sum_mat[2,] <- c(0,sy_s,0) 
sum_mat[3,] <- c(0,0,sa2_s)

demo_s <- pop0*sum_mat                  # Matrix transition process

pop1 <- c(sum(demo_s[1,]),sum(demo_s[1,]),sum(demo_s[1,]),
        sum(demo_s[2,]),sum(demo_s[2,]),sum(demo_s[2,]),
        sum(demo_s[3,]),sum(demo_s[3,]),sum(demo_s[3,]))

pop0  <- c(pop0[1],pop0[4],pop0[7])     # Extract N calves, yearlings,  adults   pre-summer
pops  <- c(pop1[1],pop1[4],pop1[7])     # Extract N calves, yearlings, adults  post-summer
ccmod <- rep(cc2,3)                     # Extract calfcow ratio
age   <- c('calf','1','2')              # Add age-class identifier
stats <- cbind(age,pop0,pops,ccmod)     # Combine the extracted values
stats <- as.data.frame(stats)     

stats$year <- i                         # Add simulation year

# CONDITION OUTPUT BY FIRST VS ALL OTHER YEARS
if (i == 1) {
 write.csv(stats,"popmodel.csv",row.names=FALSE)
} else {
  write.table(stats, file="popmodel.csv", append=T,   row.names=F,col.names=F,sep=",")
}
}
```

Comment: Wrap the whole simulation in a function and use `replicate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to place the simulation code in a function and use `replicate`. For example, the following is equivalent to your code but uses matrix operations to be more concise and, for me, easier to follow:

```
set.seed(1)     

#Transition matrices

ageing_T <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
            calves yearlings adults
  calves         0         0      0
  yearlings      1         0      0
  adults         0         1      1 
"))

reproduction_T <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
            calves yearlings adults
  calves         0         1      1
  yearlings      0         0      0
  adults         0         0      0
"))

step <- function(state, fecundity, mortality) {
  ((fecundity * reproduction_T) + diag(3)) %*% ((1-mortality) * ageing_T) %*% state
}

sim <- function(init, nyears) {
  qx <- rnorm(nyears,mean=0.1,sd=.05)       
  cc <- c(0.46,0.33,0.16,0.36,0.42)   
  Reduce(function(s,i) step(s, cc[i], qx[i]), 1:nyears, init=init, acc=TRUE)
}
```

This produces one simulated run:

```
sim(c(calves=250, yearlings=250, adults=250), 5)
```

This produces 100 of them

```
s <- replicate(100, sim(c(calves=250, yearlings=250, adults=250), 5), simplify=FALSE)
```

The output of the 100th simulation at the end of the 5th year (counting starts at 1 and ends at 6), for example is stored in `s[[100]][[6]]`

Comment: Very concise! I like the use of %*%. Curious what the 's' is doing in the Reduce function?

Comment: Also, the example code I used in this question was a portion of what I'm working with.  I'm working with 2 staged process (reproduction and winter mortality). Do you recommend I expand on your functions or start a new function where I call in the values of the reproduction simulations?

Comment: First question: In the reduce, the `s` is representing the current state at each time period. Study `?Reduce`. Second question: It's generally good practice to 'factor' your code. So, I would represent each step by clearly named small functions or transition matrices. This tends to make your code largely self-documenting and easy to read.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and your help!